# Turkish character cannot be entered in genymotion

Tags: android, utf-8, character, emulation, genymotion

I have a pc with Turkish keyboard layout and i'm using genymotion and added a virtual device.

When i enter "ş" while using virtual device in genymotion it enters "015f"

How to fix that and add support for entering turkish characters using pc keyboard when using a virtual device in genymotion ?